# What rocket uses the largest percentage of Fuel/Oxidizer before liftoff?

Tags: launch, fuel, history, efficiency

inspired by this question: [How much propellant is used up until liftoff?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/34893/how-much-propellant-is-used-up-until-liftoff/34895#34895)
which asks how much propellant (fuel/oxidizer) a typical rocket uses before liftoff. What has been or is the most non-typical rocket that uses a large percentage of propellant before liftoff? For clarity I am looking for the largest delta in rocket mass between finishing fueling and liftoff

Comment: The clear answer is a [RUD](https://youtu.be/fv7ucYAwXy0?t=11) mission.  Great advances have been made in the propellant use before liftoff on this front.

Comment: My guess is [Falcon Heavy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wbSwFU6tY1c&t=21m50s) which started ignition at around T-7s and didn't seem to lift off until T+1s.